# Add Marquee effect to row in table which have Red Background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an table with 7 rows for and 2 tabs for Sunday and  Monday. It will highlight with red color the particular row based on current time. 
I was wondering if it was possible to add

```
<marquee>My first Row</marquee>
```

effect to the particular row which is highlighted with red background and when second row is highlighted then automatically marquee effect moves to that row.

Here is the code for my table

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName, today) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent =
    document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  if (typeof today == 'undefined') {
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  } else {
    tablinks[today].className += " active";
  }
}

let now = new Date().getHours() * 100 + new
Date().getMinutes();
let times = [900, 1000, 1015];
let classes = ['ra1', 'ra3', ];
let selected = classes[times.reduce((acc, curr, idx) => now >=
  curr ? idx : acc)];
if (selected){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(selected);
  for(var i=0;i<elements.length; i++){
      elements[i].style.background = 'red';
      elements[i].innerHTML = "<marquee>" + elements[i].innerHTML + "</marquee>";
 }
}
```

```css
.tabcontent { display: none }
```

```html
<div class="tab" style="margin-top: 1.6%;  ">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Sun0') ">Sun</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Mon0')">Mon</button>

</div>

<div id="Sun0" class="tabcontent" id="np">


  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table>
      <col width="65%">
      <col width="35%">
      <tr>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Time</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="ra1">10:15-11:00AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Sunday </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="ra3">11:00-11:45AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Sunday</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="Mon0" class="tabcontent">

  <!--Monnday-->
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table>
      <col width="65%">
      <col width="35%">
      <tr>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Time</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="ra1">10:15-11:00AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Monday</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="ra3">11:00-11:45AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Monday</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The [`<marquee>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) element is obsolete are you sure you want to use it?

Comment: well if there is any new alternative, I'd be happy to use that one then.

Comment: There are no new alternatives, you could use jQuery and a marquee plugin

Comment: and what is the best way to achieve such one effects. I would be really glad if you'd help me with coding.

Answer (score 1):

Since marquee element is obsolete you will have to rely on css animation or 3rd party plugin to achive that,

using css you can assign css class(for ex : marquee) where you assigning red backgroud to row and on that class you can write following css:

```css
.marquee {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.marquee td {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;  /* show the marquee just outside the paragraph */
    animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}

.marquee td:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused
}

/* Make it move */
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>test 2</td>
  </tr>
   <tr class="marquee">
    <td>test 4</td>
    <td>test 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: well, indeed is half battle. As I have stated that I have 7 rows and red backgound shifts from one row to another in interval of 45 minutes...so I would like to get Marquee effect in row where there is red background. I think any javascript or jquery would be any help but I don't know how to proceed.